# reading a file: permission denied

Tags: linux

I have set these permissions on a file:

```
----r--r-x 1 rick rick       50 Nov 20 18:39 hello_world
```

Now I try to open the file with user rick who is a member of the group rick.

```
rick@ubuntu:~/Documents$ cat hello_world
cat: hello_world: Permission denied
```

Why can't he read it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the accessing process has userid "rick", *only* the owning-user permissions, which forbid reading, are checked.  Only if the accessing process does *not* have the same userid as the owner of the file will the kernel consider the possibility that it might be a member of the file's group.

Any process running as the owning user of a file can use the `chmod` system call to set its permission bits to whatever they want, so denying read or write access to the owning user is ineffective as a *security* measure, but it can still be a useful *safety* measure.  In other words, you can use the permission bits to prevent a file from being clobbered by its owning user *by accident*, but not *on purpose*.

Comment: +1: I was wondering why user cannot read if it is in the group that can read. (also, nice nick ;)

Answer (score 10):

Your permissions are set now to `read` just for "group" and "others".

As said in the comments, the user `rick` does belong to the group, but what counts is the fact that is the owner, so the permissions checked are the ones on the first column, which happen to be `---`, that is `0`. Hence, the `group` is not taken into consideration.

Change the permissions to something more normal :)

```
chmod 644 hello_world
```

Then you will be able to read it. As the permissions go as follows:

```
4 read
2 write
1 execute
```

`6` means read + write.

Comment: I was trying something but I am just wondering why this doesn't work because rick normally should has the permission to read it because he is in the group.

Comment: But why would an owner not have permissions set?

Comment: @user3013395 But he *is* the owner, so the permissions that apply to him are the three first ones.

Comment: oh ok, I get it now. I forgot about that. Thanks!